# How do I encode HTTP GET query strings in Perl?

Tags: perl, http, escaping, uri

This question is somewhat related to [What’s the simplest way to make a HTTP GET request in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134858/whats-the-simplest-way-to-make-a-http-get-request-in-perl).

Before making the request via `LWP::Simple` I have a hash of query string components that I need to serialize/escape. **What's the best way to encode the query string?** It should take into account spaces and all the characters that need to be escaped in valid URIs. I figure it's probably in an existing package, but **I'm not sure how to go about finding it.**

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $base_uri = 'http://example.com/rest_api/';
my %query_hash = (spam => 'eggs', foo => 'bar baz');
my $query_string = urlencode(query_hash); # Part in question.
my $query_uri = "$base_uri?$query_string";
# http://example.com/rest_api/?spam=eggs&foo=bar+baz
$contents = get($query_uri);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::Escape) does what you want.

```
use URI::Escape;

sub escape_hash {
    my %hash = @_;
    my @pairs;
    for my $key (keys %hash) {
        push @pairs, join "=", map { uri_escape($_) } $key, $hash{$key};
    }
    return join "&", @pairs;
}
```

Comment: Shortly: sub escape_hash{my %h = @_; return join '&', map{join '=', map uri_escape($_), $_, $h{$_}} keys %h}

Comment: I though of doing that too, but nesting maps just didn't look right to me.

Comment: Map inside for(each) with push sounds same complicated for me but it introduce unneeded temporary variable.

Answer (score 28):

[URI::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI-1.37/URI/Escape.pm) is probably the most direct answer, as other have given, but I would recommend using a [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/) object for the entire thing.  URI automatically escapes the GET parameters for you (using URI::Escape).

```
my $uri = URI->new( 'http://example.com' );
$uri->query_form(foo => '1 2', bar => 2);
print $uri; ## http://example.com?foo=1+2&bar=2
```

As an added bonus, [LWP::Simple's](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=lwp%3A%3Asimple&mode=all) *get* function will take a [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/) object as it's argument instead of a string.

Answer (score 5):

[URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) is far simpler than `URI::Escape` for this. The method [query_form()](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI#uri-query_form) accepts a hash or a hashref:

```
use URI;
my $full_url = URI->new('http://example.com');
$full_url->query_form({"id" => 27, "order" => "my key"});
print "$full_url\n";     # http://example.com?id=27&order=my+key
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the module [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) to build the URL with the query parameters:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use URI;

my $uri_object = URI->new('http://example.com/rest_api/');
$uri_object->query_form(spam => 'eggs', foo => 'bar baz');

$contents = get("$uri_object");
```

I found this solution [here](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch05_02.htm).

Comment: Although solutions using map and URI::Escape are elegant ... this seems simplest and thus best to me.

Answer (score 2):

[URI::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) is the module you are probably thinking of.