# yahoo answers API

Tags: api, yahoo

I want to make use of the Yahoo answers API to extract the answers, I have got my consumer key which I guess is ncessary to get an access to the answers posted on the website. Can anybody guide me as to how can I make use of this API from my application.

Comment: Not without some details of what your application is and what you've already tried, no.

Comment: say i want to get the answers for a particular question, how should i get it, like what syntax should i use, i am coding in perl.

Comment: Related: [Yahoo Answers API not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21943000/55075)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since you expanded on your question, I'll point you in the right direction at least:

You say you want to get the answers for a particular question. 
That is achieved by making a GET request to the [getQuestion](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/getQuestion.html) method, which is documented at that link, so I won't repeat the instructions here.

This method requires you to know the Yahoo! Answers `question_id`, which you can either hard-code by taking it from the URL of a known question, or search for it using the other API methods such as [questionSearch](http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html).

The response you get back will be XML, and the answers to the specific question will be in there - among other data such as the answerer's nickname, timestamps etc.

You'll need to parse this response to get the info you need.

If you need help making a GET request using Perl, I'd take a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134858/whats-the-simplest-way-to-make-a-http-get-request-in-perl) first, but it's essentially:

```
use LWP::Simple;
$contents = get("http://YOUR_URL_HERE");
```

Comment: Is there any way to get all the categories using the Yahoo Answers API